# Python Connection to Postgres over SSH- Incorrect port?

Tags: python, postgresql, ssh, psycopg2

I am trying to connect to a postgres database over an ssh server. On postico, it works, and looks something like this:

[image]

When I copy the url from postico, it looks like this:

```
postgresql+ssh://ubuntu@example-ec2-host.com/exampleusername:examplePassword@example-rds-host.com/exampledb
```

However, when I try to implement it in python, it connects successfully to the SSH server, but cannot connect to the postgres successfully.

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "example-rds-host.com" (X.X.X.X), port 56804 failed: Operation timed out
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

My code:

```
ssh_tunnel = SSHTunnelForwarder(
        (“example-ec2-host.com”, 22),
        ssh_username="ubuntu",
        ssh_private_key= ‘xRedactedx/Desktop/examplekey’,
        remote_bind_address=(“example-rds-host.com”, 5432)
    )
ssh_tunnel.start()
conn_string = "host='{}' dbname='{}' user='{}' password='{}' sslmode='{}' port='{}'".format(host, “exampledb” , ”exampleusername” ,”examplepassword”, ssl_mode, ssh_tunnel.local_bind_port)
self.connection = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
```

Comment: After you created an SSH tunnel, you have to connect to `localhost`, and the tunnel will forward the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to connect to localhost, since this is a port forward.

Answer (score 0):

I'll a example of mine that is working

```
import psycopg2
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

with SSHTunnelForwarder(
    (hostname_ssh, port_ssh),
    ssh_username=username_ssh,
    ssh_pkey=key_filename_ssh,
    remote_bind_address=(ENDPOINT, PORT)
) as tunnel:
    print(f'SSH Tunnel working: Local bind port #{tunnel.local_bind_port}')
    db_connection = psycopg2.connect(
        host='127.0.0.1', 
        port=tunnel.local_bind_port,
        database=DBNAME,
        user=USER,
        password=passcode)
    
    db_cursor = db_connection.cursor()
    # SELECT
    db_cursor.execute('''
                            SELECT COUNT(*)
                            FROM table
                      ''')
    records = db_cursor.fetchall()
    print(records)
    db_cursor.close()
    db_connection.close()
```